# Count # of Saturdays given a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

[image]

I have a datetime field and a net field. The Sat Count field is done by `=IIf(DatePart("w",Fields!DespatchDate.Value)=7,1,0)`

- I want to total the count of the Saturdays given a starting date and end date (typically a month).
  I tried `=Sum(IIf(DatePart("w",Fields!DespatchDate.Value)=7,1,0)` but the total is wrong.
- I also want to count Saturdays for rest of the month, e.g there's a missing 3rd Saturday in the picture.
- I also want to do a total of the Net for Saturdays.

Can you point me in the direction. I can do it in SQL or in SSRS

Comment: Can you give us your input table and output table? I think given table does not contain `datetime` field.

Comment: Do you want to count a saturday in the date range even if there is no despatch for that saturday? It appears that one of the saturday in your image is missing.

Comment: @Trang Le - Interesting that you accepted the other answer.. because it won't be counting your "Missing" 3rd Saturday or any missing saturday or Sunday between your start and end dates for that matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that we do not have any Input or desired output provided, I am assuming that You just want to count Saturdays in a given range:

```
Select COUNT(*), SUM(Net) 
FROM table 
WHERE Day# = 7 AND Date BETWEEN '2021-02-16' AND '2021-02-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count saturdays even if it is not part of your dataset, what you need to do is pad out all your dates for the given range and then join it to your base data set.

This would ensure that it accounts for ALL days of the week regardless of a dispatch event occuring on that date / day.

Below is some SQL code that might help you make a start.

```
declare @startdate date = '2021-02-01'
declare @enddate date = '2021-02-28'

if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#dates') is not null
drop table #dates

;WITH mycte AS
(
  SELECT CAST(@startdate AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 < @enddate
)

SELECT  DateValue into #dates
FROM    mycte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

select 
d.DateValue
, datepart(weekday,d.DateValue) as day_no 
,case when datepart(weekday,d.DateValue)  = 7 then isnull(t.net,0) else 0 end as sat_net
,case when datepart(weekday,d.DateValue)  = 1 then isnull(t.net,0) else 0 end as sun_net

from #dates d

left join your_table t
    on d.DateValue = t.some_date

drop table #dates
```

Since I don't know what your required output is, I cannot summarise this any further. But you get the idea!